# System.Security.Cryptography throws exception after migration to .net 5

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I recently migrated my blazor project from **.net core** to **.net 5**. After the migration I'm receiveing the following exception

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: SystemSecurityCryptographyAlgorithms_PlatformNotSupported at System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael..ctor()
```

for the following code

```
RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged
{
    KeySize = 256,
    BlockSize = 128,
    Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
    Mode = CipherMode.CBC
};
```

when I run it on **Linux**. Before the migration this instantiation worked as expected and it still works on **Windows**.

Furthermore: I also get the same exception for other classes of the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace (e.g. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`).

Does someone have an idea what the reason for this behaviour could be and how to solve it?

Comment: PlatformNotSupportedException is hardly the most ambiguously named exception. What you're asking for isn't supported on the Linux platform

Comment: As stated, this worked in .net core, so I don't see why it wouldn't in .net 5?

Comment: As a side note, the `RijndaelManaged` class is depreciated and Microsoft recommends using the `Aes` class instead. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: @bisen2 Isn't RijndaelManaged using the aes class internally? But thanks, I will look into that

Comment: @91378246 You are right. I just peeked at the .NET Core implementation and it is pretty much a wrapper around `Aes`, but the .NET Framework version is not. My guess is the left the warning about using Aes instead for Framework users.

Comment: Read this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/cryptography-apis-not-supported-on-blazor-webassembly
 Microsoft is unable to ship OpenSSL as a dependency in the Blazor WebAssembly configuration. We attempted to work around this by trying to integrate with the browser's SubtleCrypto API. Unfortunately, it required significant API changes that made it too hard to integrate